# Powershell script to update list column from another column Conditional

Tags: list, powershell, column, updatelistitems, conditional

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the scenario:

I have a powershell script which I am using from another post on stackexchange.

I have two fields in a list, the script copies the value from one field into the other and works great however, I would like to add some conditional logic into the script.

`TestPublishedDate` gets updated by `testupdatedate` field however, I would like for `TestPublishedDate` only to be updated if it is empty.

Here is the script I am using:

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell Snapin which adds SharePoint specific cmdlets
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

#Variables that we are going to use for list editing
$listName = "Approvals"

#Get the SPWeb object and save it to a variable
$web = Get-SPWeb http://discoverydev09/

#Get the SPList object to retrieve the "Demo List"
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]


#Get all items in this list and save them to a variable
$items = $list.items

#Go through all items
foreach($item in $items)
{
    $user = $item["testupdatedate"]
    #Change the value of the "Title" column
    $item["TestPublishedDate"] = $user

    #Update the item
    $item.Update()

}
```

I am sure it is something simple, the list will need to run daily on a list with over 5000 items. If there are any tips on making this script more streamlined please feel free to let me know!

Or even if PnP could be used to make this easier?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using below code:

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell Snapin which adds SharePoint specific cmdlets
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

#Variables that we are going to use for list editing
$listName = "Approvals"

#Get the SPWeb object and save it to a variable
$web = Get-SPWeb http://discoverydev09/

#Get the SPList object to retrieve the "Demo List"
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]


#Get all items in this list and save them to a variable
$items = $list.items

#Go through all items
foreach($item in $items)
{
    $user = $item["testupdatedate"]
    #Change the value of the "Title" column
    $testPublishedDate = $item["TestPublishedDate"]

    if(!$testPublishedDate)
    {
        $item["TestPublishedDate"] = $user
    }
    #Update the item
    $item.Update()

}
```

Comment: hi @Ganesh Sanap Thanks for the response, this works but i am unsure how it works out the site URL etc. Also this still updates the TestPublisheddate even if there is a value, I need it to ONLY update the field if it is empty..

Comment: You are passing your site URL at line `$web = Get-SPWeb http://discoverydev09/`?

Comment: no Problem, Its because i did not join the two scripts. in terms of the conditional logic your help would be appreciated! thanks

Comment: Yes. You need to merge the code. I have just written `for` block. Please upvote ( ^ ) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). So that it will be easy for other users to find the correct answers.

Comment: Hey Ganesh, is it possible for you to merge the code for me to make sure i do not have any duplicates? Also do you know of a way to make it work so that TestPublishedDate only gets updated if it is null?

Comment: Refer the updated code. It will update `TestPublishedDate` only if it is null.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, it worked a charm!

Comment: Welcome. Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Thanks again for the resolution, just a query If the testupdateddate was in a seperate list within the site how would the code differ?